# Why zsh doesnt have shift+arrow (left/rigth/up/down) shortcut on VM ARM machines?

Tags: terminal, zsh, macos, parallels

I'm a new user of ARM arch (MacOS main OS) laptop, and I don't know why the VM I installed doesn't have this shortcut.

Anyone knows how to add this type of shortcut? I tried a lot of different stuff without success.

Thanks!

- bind <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> to select one word backwards

  ```
  bindkey "^[[1;2D" backward-word-end;
  ```
- bind <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to select one word forwards

  ```
  bindkey "^[[1;2C" forward-word-end;
  ```
- bind <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> to select to the beginning of the line

  ```
  bindkey "^[[1;2A" beginning-of-line-text;
  ```
- bind <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> to select to the end of the line

  ```
  bindkey "^[[1;2B" end-of-line;
  ```

These are the commands I have tried to add to `.zshrc` and none of them worked.

Main operating system is MacOS and I am using Parallels with Kali Linux 2022.2

Comment: The actual terminal emulator in use isn't stated.  Most of the GUI terminals copy xterm, for which the binding should work.  The Linux console generally (unless specially configured) won't send those sequences.

Comment: So actually u cant use that kind of commands on Kali ARM arch??